Minimisation for the function $g(x) = wL + rK,$ subject to function $f(L,K) = L^\lambda + K^\gamma$
For the function: $f(L,K) = L^\lambda + K^\gamma $. The value for $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ is not given.
Minimise the function $g(x) = wL + rK$, subject to the constraint $L^\lambda + K^\gamma = q$

Is it true for there to be diminishing marginal rate of substitution ($\frac{\frac{df}{dL}}{\frac{df}{dK}}$), $\lambda$ and $\gamma$ has to be between $0$ and $1$?
I am trying to minimise $g(x)$ for inputs $L$ and $K$ to produce $q$ quantity of output, is it possible to do so with this function via lagrangian multiplier? I have tried to do so but the derivations ended up being too complicated.

